# AWS - Running multiples EC2 sharing same httpd vhosts files?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vhosts

We are currently using Amazon Web Services with EC2 through Beanstalk (Autoscalling/Load balancer). So we have a group of multiples EC2 servers, each of them have an httpd (Apache web server).

We want them to share the same vhosts files, so they can handled same websites: what we did is to mount a S3 bucket using S3FS, and have uploaded our vhosts files on it.

Now, all our EC2 share the same vhosts files on our S3 bucket.

But if we have to update/delete/create new vhost file, then we'll have to reload httpd configuration on each of our running EC2. So, we could have a script that will SSH auth on each of them to execute "apache2 reload" command, but seem's to be a not really scallable solution (could take a lot of time).

Is there any pro solution to:

- handle same vhosts of various EC2 instances?
- reload configuration (I mean execute the same script) on all this EC2 instances?

I read about "user data" for IAM or puppet management tools, but seems to be available only while creating new EC2 instance, not to update their configuration...

Thanks for any tips/tutorials!